# indexes of NSTableView rows

Tags: cocoa, nstableview

I sink index of first row in tableview is '0' it is Correct?

If yes, HOW can I make so index of first row in tableview become  '1' ?

this is need because my DataSourse start from '1', and I need that:

[myTableView selectedRow] = [myData row]
but no 
[myTableView selectedRow] = [myData (row-1)]

Answer (score 2):

Indexes in programming almost always start at 0, and the NSTableView is no exception. There is no way to change that so you always have to subtract or add 1 from the index as needed, I'm afraid.